# Rails nested resource routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a bunch of products that should be rendered outside of the normal application view, and I want those to be nested under "product" in the URL, like this:

```
http://example.com/product/foo
http://example.com/product/bar
```

"product" is simply a namespace and not actually a resource.  I just want to nest it to make the URL as clear as possible.  How do I configure my route to accomplish that without giving CRUD functionality to a non-existent product resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`namespace`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

in `routes.rb`

```
namespace :product do
  resources :foo
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `scope`, it's specifically for what you're trying to do:

```
scope :product do
  resorces :foo
end
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like scope accomplishes the URL format that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
namespace :product do
  match '/foo', :to => '.....'
  match '/bar', :to => '.....'
end
```